# Is an IHttpClientFactory that is injected via DI into a ServiceBusTrigger Azure function reused or recreated for each trigger?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions, dotnet-httpclient

I have an Azure Function project with one ServiceBusTrigger. This might trigger rapidly within a short timespan as messages are added to the service bus queue. It is my understanding that when injecting an IHttpClientFactory into an Azure Functions project, the factory will be added transiently, that is to my understanding once per function execution.

As far as I can tell from the documentation, this is not ideal here - for such a function I would certainly want one HttpClientFactory to reuse every time the function method is triggered, and then create HttpClients through httpClientFactory.CreateClient(), right? I am afraid that by transiently adding IHttpClientFactories through DI, they will each use their own connection pool, and in turn potentially flood the connection limit.

Can anyone tell me if I understand this correctly, and if I do, what can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`IHttpClientFactory` is registered as singleton when added by  `services.AddHttpClient()` so it is being shared instead of re-created everytime. Check the code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L22)

About `HttpClient` object creation - check the documentation from Microsoft - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

The issue isn't really with HttpClient per se, but with the default constructor for HttpClient, because it creates a new concrete instance of `HttpMessageHandler`, which is the one that has sockets exhaustion and DNS changes issues.

To address the issues mentioned above and to make `HttpClient` instances manageable, .NET Core 2.1 introduced the `IHttpClientFactory` interface which can be used to configure and create `HttpClient` instances in an app through Dependency Injection (DI) which manages the lifetime of `HttpMessageHandler` to avoid the mentioned problems/issues that can occur when managing `HttpClient` lifetimes.

Internally, each time a `HttpClient` object is asked to create from the IHttpClientFactory, a new instance is returned. But each `HttpClient` uses an `HttpMessageHandler` that's pooled and reused by the `IHttpClientFactory` to reduce resource consumption, as long as the `HttpMessageHandler's` lifetime hasn't expired.

Read the detailed benefits in the mentioned link.

Comment: Yes, but aren't the IHttpClientFactories themself created for each instance of function execution? Do all of the IHttpClientFactories deal with the HttpMessageHandler in a thread-safe way, or is a unique instance of the HttpMessageHandler linked to each one of the IHttpClientFactories?

Comment: How are you adding `HttpClient`? via - `services.AddHttpClient();`? If that's the way, then is it not being injected as singleton instance?

Comment: I add it through Startup.cs: services.AddHttpClient() - yes.

Then in the function class, I inject an IHttpClientFactory as a constructor parameter. And then I get HttpClients from _httpClientFactory.CreateClient() inside my function that has a [ServiceBusTrigger] (this can trigger multiple times in a short timespan). 

Is it so that the _httpClientFactory object will be shared for all of the trigger executions? Or will they all have their own _httpClientFactory object?

Comment: To answer the question from the title itself, `IHttpClientFactory` is registered as a singleton by default, so the factory instance itself will be shared.

Comment: Thank you. I read other places that it was created transiently, but I guess that's not the case, then.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 if you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: This answer already includes that information in the first paragraph